# How to get weather for time and place?

Tags: php, calendar, weather, weather-api

There are a number of widgets that allow pre-set address and give the current forecast, but I have a different requirement.

I need to send a date and an address, and get the currently predicted weather for that place.

Is that possible?  How could I achieve this?  If it matters, I use PHP.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: For which country? What kind of addresses? Most widgetable weather forecasts I've seen will accept a postal/zip code for location, so getting something like the USPS's master zip code database would be one place to start for American forecasts.

Comment: United States and really any format of the address.  I have no problem getting postal addresses.  I have a problem getting the weather for postal address and specified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this can help you.

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/
```

**EDIT :**

Probably these can help you

[Weather prediction algorithm variety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511074/weather-prediction-algorithm-variety)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305127/free-weather-api

Comment: The Yahoo api requiers researching their location id ahead of time.  That isn't useful for dynamic applications which need to access different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Please, go to http://www.amplio.ch/blog/web-development/google-weather-api/ it's very clear and useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a description of the steps required here in this post, or it risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'.